# Converting -Infinity to Zero

Tags: javascript

I am working on some calculation and my calculation result is giving me `NaN`.
So I used something like below which converts it `0` which was fine

```
Number((((0-0)/0)*100).toFixed(2)) || 0
```

until the result is -Infinity and i found out that `-Infinity` is numeric value. So now i did something like below to convert `-Infinity` to `0`

```js
var result = Number((((0-18)/0)*100).toFixed(2)) || 0
if (result == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY || result == Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)
{
    result=0;
 console.log(result)
}
```

This is solving the problem but is there a shorter or better approach?

Comment: Just don't divide by zero

Comment: Agreed with @Andreas. Dividing by zero is generally useless.

Comment: Although dividing zero is useless, you can achieve this using ternary
result = (Math.abs(Number((((0-18)/0)*100).toFixed(2))) == Infinity) ? 0 :  Number((((0-18)/0)*100).toFixed(2)) || 0;

Comment: @Daniel.V - which really isn't shorter :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Javascript exists isFinite() that returns if a number is finite or not. So:

```js
var result = isFinite(Number((((0-18)/0)*100).toFixed(2))) || 0;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way would be using bitwise Not operator:

```
var result = ~~Number((((0-18)/0)*100).toFixed(2))
```

Which executes a lot faster than other methods and is shorter to write.

Answer (score 1):

I second the answer from @Riccardo Gai.  Another approach could be to make use of the below 2 points **in Javscript**.

```
**Any number % Infinity  ===  number** 

**(Infinity || -Infinity) % Infinity ===  NaN**
```

So you can basically rewrite your code as...

```
Number((((0-18)/0)*100).toFixed(2)) % Infinity || 0
```

You can try out the below snippets..

```js
console.log(Number((((0-0)/3)*100).toFixed(2)) % Infinity || 0);
console.log(Number((((0-1)/0)*100).toFixed(2)) % Infinity || 0);
console.log(Number((((1-0)/0)*100).toFixed(2)) % Infinity || 0);
console.log(Number((((1-2)/0)*100).toFixed(2)) % Infinity || 0);
console.log(Number((((1-2)/2)*100).toFixed(2)) % Infinity || 0);
console.log(Number((((0-18)/0)*100).toFixed(2)) % Infinity || 0);
```

Comment: @axiac Well in javascript...Yes... Else  No :)

Answer (score 1):

> This is solving the problem but is there a shorter or better approach?

The correct approach is to never divide by zero.

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var c = 3;

var result;
if (c != 0) {
  result = ((a-b)*100)/c;
} else {
  // Zero is neither the correct result nor a good replacement for it
  // The correct approach here is to throw an exception
  result = 0;
}
```

Comment: Someone deleted their comment on my answer. No hard feelings brother :). I was just trying to help someone. I edited my answer based on your deleted comment. My upvote for u :).. Good day :)